# Frustrated with Visual Studio 2012 on Windows Server 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, belongs-to, windows-server-2012, root

Im trying to keep to best practises and not run as the machines administrator, so im running under a user account, marked as an administrator.

VS2012 *needs* to be run as administrator, so ive marked the shortcut as 'run as administrator'.

However, VS2012 is also associated with the various files it specialises in (`.cpp`, `.cs` etc).

The problem is, when i double click any of these files, which will then load inside VS2012, VS2012 has loaded in 'User Mode', and reverts to being troublesome (cannot save files, cannot launch iis when debugging etc).

Is there any solution?

I tried to mark 'devenv.exe' in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE to 'run as administrator' but this throws the error `'There was a problem sending the command to the program'` when I double click on an associated file.

Comment: As far as I understand the behavior with Windows Server 2008 R2 is different?

Comment: Why don't you give Explorer a rest and type Ctrl+O in VS?  Or change your access rights to the folder that stores the projects?  Or use your Documents folder? This problem is located 3 feet in front of the monitor, it is not a VS2012 problem.

Comment: @HansPassant So youre basically scrapping the 'associate a program with a file' feature. Thanks

Comment: So you're basically scrapping the Documents feature?  Ask the server admin to give you access rights to your source code folders.

Comment: @HansPassant I have access to these folders. I am an administrator (just not _The_ administrator)

Comment: Clearly you don't when you get permission errors if you don't run VS elevated.  Being an administrator merely gives you the right to elevate.  You can ask questions about this at superuser.com

Answer (score 3):

- Mark 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
  11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe' to 'run as administrator'
- In `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs\Set

  Associations`, order by 'Current Default'.
- Change each entry from 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2012' to 'Microsoft
  Visual Studio Version       Selector'